# My cat always hungry

Tags: cats, diet, feeding

My cat had babies 2 weeks back and now whenever she sees me she starts to meow, giving me a sign that she is hungry.
But after eating, 5 to 10 minutes later she starts to meow again. She is a normal sized pet cat.
I don't know what to do about her hunger. She did eat a lot in her pregnancy.
I usually give her meat & chicken, but now when I feed her the same amount she vomits.
What should I do to not keep her hungry and not make her sick? A special diet?

Comment: Welcome to Pets Stack Exchange! :) I'm not entirely clear what question you are asking here. Could you edit your question to clarify, please? You may wish to check out [ask], if you haven't already, for some tips.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely take your cat in for a checkup. Any time you notice a change in your cat, you should take her in. A lot of the time it's very hard to tell if a cat is ill, so any change at all should be checked out, to be safe.

While you're there, ask what your cat's diet should look like while she's nursing. Producing milk takes a lot of calories, so it's likely she should be eating more anyways.

That said, vomiting soon after eating is relatively common in cats. One of the reasons this might happen is if the cat wolfs its food down too fast. If your cat is the kind to not overeat, then it could make sense to just leave food out for her all the time. That way she can eat at her leisure, rather than when she's so hungry she'll wolf it down. It may also make sense to feed her this way while she's nursing only, and go back to the normal routine when she's no longer nursing.